# Adminer does not support accessing a database without a password, using mongodb

Tags: kubernetes, adminer

This is my yaml for the adminer:

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: adminer-1598029219
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: adminer
    helm.sh/chart: adminer-0.1.5
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: adminer-1598029219
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8000
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: adminer
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: adminer-1598029219
---
# Source: adminer/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: adminer-1598029219
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: adminer
    helm.sh/chart: adminer-0.1.5
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: adminer-1598029219
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: adminer
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: adminer-1598029219
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: adminer
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: adminer-1598029219
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: adminer
          image: "dockette/adminer:full"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          env:
          - name: ADMINER_PLUGINS
            value:
          - name: ADMINER_DESIGN
            value: pepa-linha
          - name: ADMINER_DEFAULT_SERVER
            value: 
          resources:
            {}
          livenessProbe:
            null
          readinessProbe:
            null
```

And this my yaml for th mongoDB

```
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: mongo
 labels:
   name: mongo
   app: mongo
spec:
 ports:
 - port: 27017
   targetPort: 27017
   name: web
 clusterIP: None
 selector:
   role: mongo

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
 name: web
spec:
 selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo # has to match .spec.template.metadata.labels
 serviceName: "mongo"
 replicas: 3
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: mongo
   spec:
     terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
     containers:
       - name: mongo
         image: mongo
         command:
           - mongod
           - "--replSet"
           - rs0
           - "--smallfiles"
           - "--noprealloc"
         ports:
           - containerPort: 27017
             name: web
         volumeMounts:
           - name: mongo-persistent-storage
             mountPath: /data/db
 volumeClaimTemplates:
 - metadata:
     name: mongo-persistent-storage
     annotations:
       volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: "fast"
   spec:
     accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
     resources:
       requests:
         storage: 1Gi
```

So my problem is that i can't log in into mongod becuse i get this from Adminer :
**Adminer does not support accessing a database without a password**. Is there any simple solution to this problem where i can log into my mongod?
P.S i run kubernetes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question can be found in [Adminer's documentation](https://www.adminer.org/en/password/):

> ### Accessing a database without a password
>
> Adminer 4.6.3 and newer does not support accessing a database without
> a password. The reason is that a forgotten Adminer uploaded on a place
> accessible by an attacker could have been used to access a database.
> There are these options:
>
> 1. Set up the database server to require a password. This is possible with all databases except SQLite and SimpleDB.
> 2. Use the  [**login-password-less**](https://raw.github.com/vrana/adminer/master/plugins/login-password-less.php)
>    [plugin](https://www.adminer.org/en/plugins/)  to set up a password
>    required by Adminer but not passed to the database
>    ([example](https://github.com/vrana/adminer/blob/master/adminer/sqlite.php)).
> 3. Use the  [**login-ip**](https://raw.github.com/vrana/adminer/master/plugins/login-ip.php)
>    [plugin](https://www.adminer.org/en/plugins/)  to check the IP address
>    and allow an empty password.
> 4. Implement the  `login`  [method](https://www.adminer.org/en/extension/)  to add your custom
>    authentication.

You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58009920/how-to-enter-adminer-without-password) helpful as well. It describes the whole process in a great detail.